# MYSQL replace issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, replace

I am having a MYSQL issue.

This is related to a gaming server.

What I am trying to do is take ITEM A and replace it with ITEM B below is the schema of the table, I want to exclude ID/NAME out of the sql and add all other fields

Basically I wanted to do this by the unique names of the items.

> Example: Fabled hope stone and Hope stone. Essentially I would like to
>   make the Fabled hope stone hold the same values as the Hope stone.

I have found an alternate solution, but this would require me to include 250+ queries PER item to change each field. and to do this with 633 rows  would be 158,230 lines of sql, which I prefer not to write. I can't think of an efficient way to do this.

**{alternate solution}**

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE name LIKE 'Hope Stone';

UPDATE items
SET hp = (
     SELECT hp
     FROM t
     WHERE name LIKE 'Hope Stone'
     )
WHERE name LIKE 'Fabled Hope Stone';

DROP TABLE t;
```

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`minstatus` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`aagi` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ac` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`accuracy` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`acha` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`adex` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`aint` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`artifactflag` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`asta` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`astr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attack` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augrestrict` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot1type` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot1visible` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`augslot2type` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot2visible` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`augslot3type` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot3visible` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`augslot4type` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot4visible` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`augslot5type` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot5visible` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`augtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`avoidance` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`awis` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bagsize` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bagslots` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bagtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bagwr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`banedmgamt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`banedmgraceamt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`banedmgbody` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`banedmgrace` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardvalue` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`book` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`casttime` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`casttime_` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`charmfile` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`charmfileid` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`classes` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`color` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`combateffects` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`extradmgskill` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`extradmgamt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`price` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`cr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`damage` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`damageshield` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deity` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`delay` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augdistiller` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`dotshielding` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`dr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clicktype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clicklevel2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`elemdmgtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`elemdmgamt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`endur` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionamt1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionamt2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionamt3` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionamt4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionmod1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionmod2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionmod3` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`factionmod4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`filename` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`focuseffect` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fvnodrop` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`haste` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clicklevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`hp` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`regen` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`icon` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`idfile` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`itemclass` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`itemtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ldonprice` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ldontheme` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ldonsold` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`light` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lore` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`loregroup` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`magic` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`mana` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`manaregen` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`enduranceregen` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`material` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`maxcharges` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`mr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`nodrop` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`norent` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`pendingloreflag` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`pr` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`procrate` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`races` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`range` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reclevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`recskill` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reqlevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sellrate` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`shielding` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`size` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skillmodtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skillmodvalue` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`slots` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clickeffect` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`spellshield` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`strikethrough` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stunresist` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`summonedflag` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tradeskills` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`favor` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`weight` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK012` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK013` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`benefitflag` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK054` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK059` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`booktype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`recastdelay` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`recasttype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`guildfavor` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK123` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK124` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attuneable` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`nopet` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`updated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`comment` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`UNK127` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`pointtype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`potionbelt` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`potionbeltslots` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stacksize` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`notransfer` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stackable` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK134` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`UNK137` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`proceffect` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`proctype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`proclevel2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`proclevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK142` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`worneffect` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`worntype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornlevel2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornlevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK147` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focustype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focuslevel2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focuslevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK152` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrolleffect` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrolltype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrolllevel2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrolllevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK157` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`serialized` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`verified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`serialization` TEXT NULL,
`source` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`UNK033` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lorefile` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`UNK014` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`svcorruption` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK038` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK060` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot1unk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot2unk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot3unk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot4unk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`augslot5unk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK120` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK121` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`questitemflag` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK132` TEXT NOT NULL,
`clickunk5` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clickunk6` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`clickunk7` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`procunk1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`procunk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`procunk3` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`procunk4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`procunk6` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`procunk7` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornunk1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornunk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornunk3` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornunk4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornunk5` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`wornunk6` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`wornunk7` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focusunk1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focusunk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focusunk3` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focusunk4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focusunk5` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`focusunk6` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`focusunk7` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrollunk1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrollunk2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrollunk3` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrollunk4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrollunk5` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scrollunk6` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`scrollunk7` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK193` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`purity` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`evolvinglevel` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clickname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`procname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`wornname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`focusname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`scrollname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`dsmitigation` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_str` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_int` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_wis` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_agi` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_dex` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_sta` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_cha` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_pr` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_dr` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_fr` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_cr` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_mr` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`heroic_svcorrup` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`healamt` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`spelldmg` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`clairvoyance` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`backstabdmg` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`elitematerial` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ldonsellbackrate` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`scriptfileid` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`expendablearrow` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`powersourcecapacity` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardeffect` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardeffecttype` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardlevel2` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardlevel` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardunk1` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardunk2` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardunk3` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardunk4` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardunk5` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bardname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`bardunk7` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK214` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK219` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK220` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK221` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK222` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK223` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK224` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK225` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK226` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK227` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK228` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK229` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK230` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK231` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK232` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK233` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK234` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK235` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK236` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK237` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK238` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK239` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK240` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK241` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UNK242` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

    "id"    "minstatus" "Name"  "aagi"  "ac"    "accuracy"  "acha"  "adex"  "aint"  "artifactflag"  "asta"  "astr"  "attack"    "augrestrict"   "augslot1type"  "augslot1visible"   "augslot2type"  "augslot2visible"   "augslot3type"  "augslot3visible"   "augslot4type"  "augslot4visible"   "augslot5type"  "augslot5visible"   "augtype"   "avoidance" "awis"  "bagsize"   "bagslots"  "bagtype"   "bagwr" "banedmgamt"    "banedmgraceamt"    "banedmgbody"   "banedmgrace"   "bardtype"  "bardvalue" "book"  "casttime"  "casttime_" "charmfile" "charmfileid"   "classes"   "color" "combateffects" "extradmgskill" "extradmgamt"   "price" "cr"    "damage"    "damageshield"  "deity" "delay" "augdistiller"  "dotshielding"  "dr"    "clicktype" "clicklevel2"   "elemdmgtype"   "elemdmgamt"    "endur" "factionamt1"   "factionamt2"   "factionamt3"   "factionamt4"   "factionmod1"   "factionmod2"   "factionmod3"   "factionmod4"   "filename"  "focuseffect"   "fr"    "fvnodrop"  "haste" "clicklevel"    "hp"    "regen" "icon"  "idfile"    "itemclass" "itemtype"  "ldonprice" "ldontheme" "ldonsold"  "light" "lore"  "loregroup" "magic" "mana"  "manaregen" "enduranceregen"    "material"  "maxcharges"    "mr"    "nodrop"    "norent"    "pendingloreflag"   "pr"    "procrate"  "races" "range" "reclevel"  "recskill"  "reqlevel"  "sellrate"  "shielding" "size"  "skillmodtype"  "skillmodvalue" "slots" "clickeffect"   "spellshield"   "strikethrough" "stunresist"    "summonedflag"  "tradeskills"   "favor" "weight"    "UNK012"    "UNK013"    "benefitflag"   "UNK054"    "UNK059"    "booktype"  "recastdelay"   "recasttype"    "guildfavor"    "UNK123"    "UNK124"    "attuneable"    "nopet" "updated"   "comment"   "UNK127"    "pointtype" "potionbelt"    "potionbeltslots"   "stacksize" "notransfer"    "stackable" "UNK134"    "UNK137"    "proceffect"    "proctype"  "proclevel2"    "proclevel" "UNK142"    "worneffect"    "worntype"  "wornlevel2"    "wornlevel" "UNK147"    "focustype" "focuslevel2"   "focuslevel"    "UNK152"    "scrolleffect"  "scrolltype"    "scrolllevel2"  "scrolllevel"   "UNK157"    "serialized"    "verified"  "serialization" "source"    "UNK033"    "lorefile"  "UNK014"    "svcorruption"  "UNK038"    "UNK060"    "augslot1unk2"  "augslot2unk2"  "augslot3unk2"  "augslot4unk2"  "augslot5unk2"  "UNK120"    "UNK121"    "questitemflag" "UNK132"    "clickunk5" "clickunk6" "clickunk7" "procunk1"  "procunk2"  "procunk3"  "procunk4"  "procunk6"  "procunk7"  "wornunk1"  "wornunk2"  "wornunk3"  "wornunk4"  "wornunk5"  "wornunk6"  "wornunk7"  "focusunk1" "focusunk2" "focusunk3" "focusunk4" "focusunk5" "focusunk6" "focusunk7" "scrollunk1"    "scrollunk2"    "scrollunk3"    "scrollunk4"    "scrollunk5"    "scrollunk6"    "scrollunk7"    "UNK193"    "purity"    "evolvinglevel" "clickname" "procname"  "wornname"  "focusname" "scrollname"    "dsmitigation"  "heroic_str"    "heroic_int"    "heroic_wis"    "heroic_agi"    "heroic_dex"    "heroic_sta"    "heroic_cha"    "heroic_pr" "heroic_dr" "heroic_fr" "heroic_cr" "heroic_mr" "heroic_svcorrup"   "healamt"   "spelldmg"  "clairvoyance"  "backstabdmg"   "created"   "elitematerial" "ldonsellbackrate"  "scriptfileid"  "expendablearrow"   "powersourcecapacity"   "bardeffect"    "bardeffecttype"    "bardlevel2"    "bardlevel" "bardunk1"  "bardunk2"  "bardunk3"  "bardunk4"  "bardunk5"  "bardname"  "bardunk7"  "UNK214"    "UNK219"    "UNK220"    "UNK221"    "UNK222"    "UNK223"    "UNK224"    "UNK225"    "UNK226"    "UNK227"    "UNK228"    "UNK229"    "UNK230"    "UNK231"    "UNK232"    "UNK233"    "UNK234"    "UNK235"    "UNK236"    "UNK237"    "UNK238"    "UNK239"    "UNK240"    "UNK241"    "UNK242"
    "11538" "0" "Forest Loop"   "3" "2" "0" "0" "3" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "7" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "3" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "0" "65535" "4278190080"    "0" "0" "0" "300000"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "757"   "IT63"  "0" "29"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "Forest Loop"   "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "65535" "0" "0" "0" "0" "5" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "18"    "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "300"   "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "300"   "0" "0" "0" "0" "2011-12-17 08:40:28"   ""  "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" ""  "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" NULL    "2011-03-21 20:37:12"   NULL    "13THFLOOR" "0" ""  "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0000000000000000000"   "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "2003-10-09 14:09:29"   "0" "70"    "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "-256"  "255"   "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
    "82746" "0" "Fabled Forest Loop"    "7" "10"    "0" "0" "7" "0" "0" "7" "0" "0" "0" "7" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "7" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "0" "65535" "4278190080"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "9" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "9" "0" "0" "0" "0" "70"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "9" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "757"   "IT63"  "0" "29"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "Fabled Forest Loop"    "0" "1" "70"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "65535" "0" "0" "0" "50"    "5" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "18"    "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "2011-12-17 08:41:34"   ""  "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" ""  "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" NULL    "2009-05-08 23:58:57"   NULL    "13THFLOOR" "0" ""  "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0000000000000000000"   "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "2005-03-31 19:47:57"   "0" "70"    "0" "0" "0" "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" ""  "-1"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
```

These are two items that I've used the above query to make exactly the same in the HP column, I want to make the "items" or entries the same except for the ID and the Name, those have to be unique

Comment: Do you want to have 2 separate items that are similar, or just rename an item?

Comment: I want to have two separate items that are similar, but with different names The items are already ingame, I wanted to make the Fabled version have the same values as the non fabled version

Comment: Your task is not clear. Would it be possible to post a small data sample (subset) and the expected result?  What **exactly** do you mean by `item` here?

Comment: By item I mean entry, or row, sorry not too familiar with SQL terms. I've posted 2 database entries I've edited, in the HP field to be identical

Answer (score 0):

You could do an UPDATE statement specifying two tables (even though it's the same table)

```
UPDATE 
    items a, 
    items b
SET 
    a.minstatus = b.minstatus,
    a.aagi = b.aagi,
    a.ac = b.ac,
    ...
    a.UNK242 = b.UNK242
WHERE 
    a.name = 'Fabled Hope Stone'
AND
    b.name = 'Hope Stone'
```

Probably want to test on a scratch database, or put it in a transaction before running however.